# c# Add new entries to a Json File

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im trying to add Members to a Json file but i cant quite figure out how to add new Members to the Existing file.

```
{
  "Members": {
    "Example1": {
      "LastOnline": "2016-05-16T12:09:04.6459345Z",
      "TimeUntillEx": "2016-05-16T12:09:04.6459345Z",
      "Paied": true
    },
  }
}
```

Problem is "Example1" is already the Name of the User. I dont know if i should try to just add more or copy the existing and edit the copied text.
Hope someone can Help.

btw. im new so sorry for any mistakes

Comment: I think you need to deserialize the JSON to a model, add entries and then serialize again.

Comment: +1 for @FailedUnitTest's answer above. Another option if you are dealing with plain text could be to build out a template for an object and do simple placeholder substitution to add new objects.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what I would do is change the `Members` property to be an `array` instead of an `object`. Then, I would do something like this:

```
//original json. Notice that I added '[ ]' to make it an array
var json = "{ 'Members': " +
             "[ " +
                 "{'Example1': " +
                     "{ 'LastOnline': '2016-05-16T12:09:04.6459345Z', " +
                       "'TimeUntillEx': '2016-05-16T12:09:04.6459345Z', " +
                       "'Paied': true" +
                     "}, " +
                 "} " +
             "] " +
           "}";

//new member
var newMember = "{ 'Example2': " +
                    "{ 'LastOnline': '2016-12-16T12:09:04.6459345Z', " +
                      "'TimeUntillEx': '2016-12-16T12:09:04.6459345Z', " +
                      "'Paied': false" +
                    "}, " +
                "}";

//parse the json
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

//get members array
var array = obj.GetValue("Members") as JArray;

//parse the new member and add it to the array
var add = JObject.Parse(newMember);

array.Add(add);

//serialize the json
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);

//print the results
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

For this, you will need

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. this is just what i needed!

Comment: Btw is there an easy way to remove an entry aswell ?

Comment: Sure @MarlonHaenen. First, if you liked the answer don't forget to upvote it as well.

Basically because you are using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`. You have the power to manipulate `JObject`s and `JArray`s as any other generic `C#` object. So, if you would like to remove something from the array. I would go and do something like:

`array.RemoveAt(1);` //this would remove the entry that we just added 

or you could do something like

`array.Remove(add);` //that would remove the object we just added.

Don't forget to serialize the object at the end though.

Comment: sadly i cant upvote since my reputation is too low O.o